# Is it possible to return a range from an IFS or SWITCH?

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am trying to simplify some 'if else if else' code by replacing it with a single `IFS` or `SWITCH` expressions. I have simplified all the code to be trivial but show the problem.

This code works and two cell values are returned:

```
= IF(CELL_REFERENCE = 1,
    {
        "A";"B"
    },
    IF(CELL_REFERENCE = 2,
        {
            "C"; "D"
        },
        {
            "E"; "F"
        }
    )
)
```

This code does not work with only the first value being returned each time:

```
= IFS(CELL_REFERENCE = 1,
    {
        "A";"B"
    },
    CELL_REFERENCE = 2,
    {
        "C"; "D"
    }
    CELL_REFERENCE = 3,
    {
        "E"; "F"
    }
)
```

The same issues happen when using `SWITCH`, with only the first value of a range being returned.

Is there a good solution for these cases, or just keep using multiple `IF` expressions?

Comment: yes it is if you input range instead of cell reference

Comment: We don't have much to go on, Annan. And I have a feeling your actual data isn't going to adapt well to whatever we can offer sight unseen. That said, my gut is that I'd go with a =ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(CELL_REFERENCE,QUERY({values, result1, result2}),{2,3},FALSE)) setup.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

You may think that behaviour of **`IFS()`** is similar to **`IF()`** and reason of having **`IFS()`** is to avoid nesting of multiple **`IF()`** but that's not so true. Yes, there are some common baselines however, there is a major difference when it comes to arrays. **`IFS()`** in a combination of arrayed output expects arrayed input - that's why you got returned single-cell output instead of arrayed output.

- let's say your **`IF()`** formula is like:

  [image]
- "converting" it into **`IFS()`** will return this (because cell **A1** is not array/range):

  [image]
- now let's add a arrayformula (ranged input):

  [image]
- also note this behaviour:

  [image] [image]